# Errors in mathemetics for calculating corrections for parallax of celestial object in Java

Tags: java, math, astronomy

I'm implementing the calculations of the book [Practical Astronomy with your Calculator or Spreadsheet](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00E6TEV3I). Until now my calculations yield exactly the same result as the example calculations in the book.

However, arriving at §39 "Calculating corrections for parallax" I encounter a difference that I fail to understand.

The task at hand is described as follows:

> As an example, let us calculate the apparent right ascension and declination of the Moon on 26
>   February 1979 at 16h 45m UT when observed from a location 60 metres above sea-level on longitude 100° W and latitude 50° N. The geocentric coordinates were α = 22h 35m 19s and δ = −7° 41′ 13′′,   and the Moon’s equatorial horizontal parallax was 1° 01′ 09′′.

The book describes the sequence of calculation as follows:
[image]

Yet *my* outcome of step 7 is −31.993415, but book says −31,99**4**415. If I do the mathematics of step 7 with the values of the book on a calculator the result is −31.99**3**415 too, so my outcome seems to be right and the book's wrong....

I could live with that but there is a difference in step 10 too. My result is -8,570634, the books result is -8.538165, a rather large difference. I've read over step 10 time and time again to see if there is an error in my code, but I don't see it.

As until now my calculations and the books calculations are exactly the same I'm stuck. Am I doing something wrong (preferred), or did the book make an error (let's hope there aren't any more...)

My Java code for this function is as follows:

```
    static EquatorialCoordinate parallax(EquatorialCoordinate body, ObserverLocation observer, ZonedDateTime zdt, double P) {
    double Hd = 15d * raha(body.α, zdt, observer.λ);
    step("α", body.α);
    step("δ", body.δ);
    step("φ", observer.φ);
    step("λ", observer.λ);
    step("h", observer.h);
    step("H", Hd);

    double H = toRadians(Hd);
    Parallax ρ = parallax(observer.φ, observer.h);

    step("P", P);
    P = toRadians(P);

    double δ = toRadians(body.δ);
    double r = 1d / sin(P);
    step("r", r);
    double ρsinφ = ρ.sin;
    double ρcosφ = ρ.cos;
    step("ρcosφ'",ρcosφ);
    step("ρsinφ'",ρsinφ);
    double Δ = atan((ρcosφ * sin(H)) / ((r * cos(δ)) - (ρcosφ * cos(H))));
    step("Δ", toDegrees(Δ));
    H += Δ;
    step("H'", toDegrees(H));
    Δ = toDegrees(Δ);
    double α$ = body.α - (Δ / 15d);
    step("α'", α$);

    double divident = (r * sin(δ)) - ρsinφ;
    double divisor = ( r * cos(δ) * cos(H) ) - ρcosφ;
    double δ$ = atan(cos(H) * (divident / divisor));
    δ$ = toDegrees(δ$);
    step("δ'", δ$);
    return new EquatorialCoordinate(α$, δ$);
}
```

The "step" function does a simple formatted printf. The output of this program is:

- α    22.588611
- δ    -7.686944
- φ    50.000000
- λ  -100.000000
- h    60.000000
- H   -31.642500
- P     1.019167
- r    56.221228
- ρcosφ'     0.644060
- ρsinφ'     0.762422
- Δ    -0.350915
- H'   -31.993414
- α'    22.612005
- δ'    -8.570634

The resulting δ' is -8° 34' 14.28" instead of -8° 32' 17"

I've replaced my calculated value of H' with the books value to see if the book contains a carried error, but even if I do so the value is wrong.

Thus... my big question is, is my implementation wrong (and where, I can't see it), or were the books calculations wrong.

(Edit:) Class is annotated with strictfp, using java.util.StrictMath.

Comment: Supposing your calculations are correct, this is most probably a result of repeated errors in `double` calculations. Try to use a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: I have a question. how did you manage to type those symbols in java code?

Comment: I second that: you have some heavy calculations here and precision errors due to the use of floating point numbers will add up. Using `BigDecimal` should help.

Comment: @svasa Java compilers accept unicode and since those "symbols" are greek _characters_ they're valid variable names. You can write some nasty stuff with that (I remember someone posting code in arabic letters here which switched between ltr and rtl) - just that you can do it doesn't mean you should do it ;)

Comment: @Thomas So how do you put those symbols in the code, you use some special keyboard ? or write something like U+10400?

Comment: @svasa You could use different keyboard settings (make your keyboard a greek one for example) or simply copy-paste them. :) I assume entering codepoints directly into the source wouldn't work but maybe your editor supports entering them without switching your keyboard. I'd still advice not to use them in code as it can get quite messy (try `int o = 0;int ο = 0;` ;) - copy it from here as the second var uses a greek omicron)

Comment: For the record, the class is annotated with strictfp, and the all the functions used are from java.util.StrictMath. As of repeated errors, no other function yet implemented seems to have a repeated error, so I'm not sure of that.

Comment: I see StrictMath uses floating-point arithmetic, as Tunaki , Thomas suggested better go with BigDecimal. See this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-math2/) and search for the word "precision" you will see statement saying : "Of course, if you really do need the extra precision, then you'll need to pick a data type with more precision, such as a double or a BigDecimal"

Comment: Extend the code to be an MCVE.

Comment: In all my other calculations double yielded the correct result. The problem is that I'm not sure if I implemented step 10 correctly, or the book is wrong., Especially with having to do `toRadians` for the cos/sin/... functions.

Comment: @user1993392, did you miss prime like in H' in the formula : atan(cos(H) * (divident / divisor))

Comment: Try to find some on-line calculator for these formulas, and see if the book is right or wrong.

Comment: @svasa Hi, I'm not sure what 'prime like' means, but you've found my error! If you post an answer I'll accept it. (The error was using H' in the divisor, where it should be H)

Comment: No problem, glad you could solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You write

```
H += Δ;
```

Which changes the value of H.

Then you write

```
double δ$ = atan(cos(H) * (divident / divisor));
```

Which uses the new version of H when it should use the old value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @svasa, I found that the divisor of step 10 should contain H, not H'.
The correct code is:

```
static EquatorialCoordinate parallax(EquatorialCoordinate body, ObserverLocation observer, ZonedDateTime zdt, double P) {
    double H = toRadians(15d * raha(body.α, zdt, observer.λ));
    P = toRadians(P);
    Parallax ρ = parallax(observer.φ, observer.h);
    double δ = toRadians(body.δ);
    double r = 1d / sin(P);
    double Δ = atan((ρ.cosφ * sin(H)) / ((r * cos(δ)) - (ρ.cosφ * cos(H))));
    double H$ = H + Δ; 
    double α$ = body.α - (toDegrees(Δ) / 15d);
    double δ$ = toDegrees(atan(cos(H$) * ((r * sin(δ) - ρ.sinφ) / (r * cos(δ) * cos(H) - ρ.cosφ))));

    return new EquatorialCoordinate(α$, δ$);
}
```